# Where does exported eclipse plug-in search for icons?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I exported an Eclipse plug-in, but I have an issue with it. There is a pushbutton, which starts the operation of the plug-in. The icon of the button (which I added in the plugin.xml) does not appear. I can see only the label of the actionbutton insted of that specific icon.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the icon (or the location of icons) into the binary build via the build.properties file. (Open it with the editor and tick the appropriate checkbox, or simply add the location in a text editor.)

Comment: Unfortunately it is included in the binary build but still not working.